# Create listener which work when I call to some Function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have

```
function doSomething(response){
   ...
}
```

need  eventlistener for working when this function is called

```
document.addEventListener('onRunFunction', function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

And when `doSomething("Text here")` work I see alert window with
"Text here".

IMPORTANT: I can't touch first(doSomething) function

Comment: Put that alert as a first line in `doSomething`. JavaScript functions don't have listeners.

Comment: I can't touch first function

Comment: Can that be seen in your question? No, it can't. You see, all the information of your case is important. Now the only answer to your question in the given dup is Lightness', voted down, though, but very true.

Comment: I find solution, but don't like that.